# If $A^2=3A$ and $A^\star A=AA^\star$, then $A=A^\star$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ is normal, i.e. 
>   $A^\star A=AA^\star$ and also satisfies the property $A^2=3A$, then $A$ is Hermitian, i.e. $A=A^\star$.

I started with right, left multiplications with 
$A, ~A^\star$, but they didn't get me somewhere.

Any hint would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is normal, it is unitarily diagonalizable so we can find a unitary matrix $U \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ such that $U^{-1} A U = D$ where $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ is diagonal and the values on the diagonal are the eigenvalues of $A$. Now, note that $A^2 = 3A$ implies that $D^2 = 3D$ so the $\lambda_i$ must satisfy $\lambda_i^2 = 3 \lambda_i$. In other words, they must be roots of $x^2 - 3x = x(x - 3)$ and so $\lambda_i \in \{ 0, 3 \}$ are real and hence $D$ is real and $A = UDU^{-1}$ is Hermitian.